# Unable to fetch object value

Tags: javascript, object

I am struggling to figure out why I am getting "undefined" when trying to fetch a certain object value.

My object, called "message" looks like this:

```
{"username":"123","password":"123"}
```

When I try to fetch either username or password with the following:

```
message.username
message['username']
```

I get "undefined".

What's the correct way to fetch the values?

Code that gets the message and displays it:

```
window.messageBus.onMessage = function(event) {
    displayText(event.data); // spits out {"username":"123","password":"123"}
}

function displayText(message) {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = message.username + ' - ' + message.password;
};
```

EDIT - The object is being received by Chromecasts "window.messageBus.onMessage" function. I assumed because I sent the message as a proper object, it should have bene spat back as a proper object, but it seems that might not be the case!

Comment: this should work can you show the full code.

Comment: Please show some code. It is impossible to tell what is wrong like this. How is the object created? How is it accessed?

Comment: Can you show us the whole code? Both ways of accessing your object are supposed to work.

Comment: Apparently the problem lies elsewhere, the object definition you've shown is correct and could be used in an assignment. You need to reveal broader context.

Comment: The edit you have made is still not enough for us to help you. Please show us your code, or maybe some output from your web browser's development console.

Comment: I have added the code from my receiver app that is outputting "undefined" after receiving a message

Answer (score 1):

Well, no idea why it wasn't working with the code I posted, as by all means it should have.

Anyway, I fixed it by using "JSON.parse()" on the "message" variable passed to "displayText()"

I was then able to use "message.username" to get the value.

Answer (score -3):

No point defining your variables in "", see the following example:

```
var person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"blue"};
alert(person.firstName);
```

That is the right way of defining and accessing the objects in Javascript

Comment: It doesn't matter.
the code @Mr Pablo wrote should work.
I'm sure he declared the object in a closure and calling it from outside or something causes the issue.